# WooCommerce shop page generates error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, server

I am using WooCommerce shop version 2.4.10 and WordPress version 4.3.1 in multisite mode.

When I try to open my shop page as a guest, I get the message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator,
>   cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
>   error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When I’m logged in as administrator, everything is OK.
Does anyone have an idea what’s going on?

Comment: Check the server’s error log.

Comment: Error log says: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_soap.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/